# JS Calendar + JSF

Tags: jsf, jscalendar

sorry about input mistakes, english its not my mother lang.
I have this code written on normal html that i managed to transform into xhtml file, i want to send the value shown on `<input id="f_date">` to `<h:inputText>`:

```
<script src="../js/jscal2.js" type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>
<script src="../js/lang/en.js" type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jscal2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/border-radius.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/steel/steel.css" />

<h:form id="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" id="cont"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input style="text-align: center" name="date" id="f_date"
        size="14" />
        <h:inputText id="f_date" value="#{solicitud.fechaI}" maxlength="10" size="10" valueChangeListener="#{solicitud.fechaIText}">
            <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="fechaI, fIni" status="statusFI"/>
        </h:inputText>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="text-align: center" name="hour" id="f_hour" size="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        :
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="text-align: center" name="minute" id="f_minute"
        size="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</h:form><script type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve">//<![CDATA[


  function updateFields(cal) {
          var date = cal.selection.get();
          if (date) {
                  date = Calendar.intToDate(date);
                  document.getElementById("f_date").value = Calendar.printDate(date, "%Y-%m-%d");
          }
          document.getElementById("f_hour").value = cal.getHours();
          document.getElementById("f_minute").value = cal.getMinutes();
  };

  Calendar.setup({
          cont         : "cont",
          showTime     : 12,
          onSelect     : updateFields,
          onTimeChange : updateFields
  });

//]]></script>
```

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reuse input element from `<h:inputText>` when setting up JS calendar. Use `inputField` argument to pass id of input generated by JSF. It could be `form1:f_date` but check html source to make sure.

EDIT:

prefix id with "form1:" in updateFields"

```
document.getElementById("form1:f_date")
```

and get rid of

```
<input style="text-align: center" name="date" id="f_date"
       size="14" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can you explain me with more details, im kinda confused about this topic because im new using this framework

Comment: I just did what you told me but its not sending the value of the JS Calendar to the h:inputText, i think im missing something to wrap both values.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your intention. Try to change input id to "form1:f_date" in updateFields, `document.getElementById("form1:f_date")`.